# C# using reference parameters

Tags: c#, reference, parameter-passing

reference parameters is only useful for valuetypes?
for example if you have a method that passes in a class, the ref keyword is useless?

```
public class someclass
{

}    

somefunction(ref someclass input)
{

}
```

Comment: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html#ref

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/186891/34397 http://stackoverflow.com/q/2193064/34397

Comment: It's useful for ref types, for example see [`Array.Resize()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348051.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You surely *could* use a ref parameter for a class type. For instance:

```
void MyClassFactory(ref MyClass newRef)
{
    newRef = new MyClass();
}

MyClass someRef = null;
MyClassFactory(ref someRef);
// Now someRef is referencing a new MyClass object.
```

And notice that the above code would **not** work without the `ref` keyword.

Comment: Note in an example like that you're better off just returning the new object, not using a `ref` param.

Comment: @Servy: I never said this is *good* code ;) My intention here is just to illustrate that one may use `ref` for reference types, and that it has distinct semantics.

Comment: If you're going to go out of your way to find an example, you could at least use one that's useful, otherwise you'll give the impression that it's not a useful feature.

Comment: @Servy: so why don't **you** do that. It's a free site after all.

Comment: Because there's a million duplicates; I don't see the need to answer the question at all, and instead voted to close as a duplicate.

Comment: @Servy: Wow. I don't see how your last comment relates to your first. You first say that I should try to give a better answer. Than you say I should have not answered at all!! But anyway, I agree there are a lot of similar questions here on SO, so point taken...

Comment: I asserted that this is not a good answer, and explained why.  You asked me why I didn't provide a better answer, to which I stated that I didn't provide a better answer because there are already lots of good answers in duplicates.  I didn't say that you shouldn't have answered at all, I simply stated that this is a low quality answer.  If you decide to take the time to turn this into a high quality answer I'd suggest you post it on the canonical answer, rather than on a duplicate here.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31410/discussion-between-rsenna-and-servy)

Answer (score 0):

ref can be useful for reference types if you need to replace the object the function was given with a new object.  For example:

```
class MyClass
{

}

class MyClass2 : MyClass
{
   public MyClass2(MyClass original)
   {
   }
}

bool UpdateMyClass(ref MyClass input)
{
   bool success = false;

   if (input != null)
   {
       //Generate a new object with some additional functionality.
       input = new MyClassWithSuperPowers(input);
       success = true;
   }

   return success;
}
```

And of course, the most obvious use case is the string class.

```
void FormatString(ref string data)
{
  data = DateTime.Now + data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is this(and I hope someone corrects me if I'm wrong):

C# contains value types(allocated on the stack), and reference types(allocated on the heap).

However, all parameters are passed by value by default, which means if you call a function

```
myFunc(myClass param) { }
...
myClass myVar = new myClass();
myFunc(myVar);
//myVar will not be changed here
```

Then a cheap copy of myVar will be created and passed into myFunc.

If you pass the same parameter by using the 'ref' keyword, then a copy of myVar is not made, and instead a reference to myVar is passed in.  Then any changes made to myVar inside myFunc would be reflected in myVar once myFunc returns.

```
myFunc(ref myClass param) { }
...
myClass myVar = new myClass();
myFunc(ref myVar);
//myVar might be changed here
```

I'm having trouble finding an article that actually talks about parameters and not just value vs. refernece *types*, but I think this is how it works.

Comment: This is not very correct.  You need to understand the different between _mutating_ an object and assigning a variable.

Comment: Read http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html